# Entity Framework migration detect something that not exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework with code first approach.

I have created a class that I mapped as table:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CdrFile>()
    .ToTable("cdrFile", schemaName)
    .HasKey(f => new { f.Id });
```

I create my migration `CdrFileMigration`. This is the **last** migration.

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "administration.cdrFiles",
        c => new
            {
                id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                name = c.String(),
                fileNameWithExtension = c.String(), // <-- See this line
                url = c.String(),
                serviceType = c.String(),
                date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                state = c.Int(nullable: false),
                operatorName = c.String(),
                acquisitionDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);
}
```

Then I updated the db. 
Some time is passed, I changed the entity `CdrFile` removing a column.
No migration has been created in the meanwhile. So I updated the database to the version **before last**. I modified the `CdrFileMigration` removing the column:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "administration.cdrFiles",
        c => new
            {
                id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                name = c.String(),
                //fileNameWithExtension = c.String(), // <-- I removed this line
                url = c.String(),
                serviceType = c.String(),
                date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                state = c.Int(nullable: false),
                operatorName = c.String(),
                acquisitionDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.id);
}
```

I updated the database again to the last migration.
The database is created correctly but if I run again the `Add-Migration` command, this file is generated

```
public partial class aa : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        DropColumn("administration.cdrFiles", "fileNameWithExtension");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AddColumn("administration.cdrFiles", "fileNameWithExtension", c => c.String());
    }
}
```

Why? I expected an empty migration instead. Infact If I run this migration, an error I obtain: "No fileNameWithExtension column to drop found"...
Can anyone help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you did not run `Add-Migration` again after you updated the database to the version before last.

EF keeps a snapshot of the model in the Database. This snapshot is updated when you run `Add-Migration`. It is not sufficient to go back to the old version and just edit the old migration file.

To fix your problem, create an empty migration using `Add-Migration`. This will update the snapshot in the DB. For example, you can just remove the `DropColumn` statements in the migration you have already created, then `Update-Database`. If you then run `Add-Migration` again, the `DropColumn` statements should no longer be generated.

To recapitulate, the correct way of editing an existing migration is:

1. `Update-Database -TargetMigration {Name of migration before migration to be edited}`
2. Delete migration files to be edited (copy content of `Up` and `Down` to scrap pad)
3. Generate migration again using `Add-Migration`. Modify as needed.
4. `Update-Database` to apply migration